# c# split integers and strings from text file and add them to two different listbox

Tags: c#, string, listbox, split, integer

I'm trying to parse sales information from text file and put them to two listboxes

The text file contains this information:

```
Sam West $10,000.00
Mae West $125,900.00
North West $2,000.00
Michelle Smith $25,000.00
John Smith $12,500.00
Martin Smith $19,900.00
David Sampson $32,500.00
Joan Sampson $5,990.00
Sam Sampson $10,000.00
Mae Sampson $125,500.00
North Sampson $2,000.00
Michelle West $25,000.00
John Johnson $12,500.00
Martin Johnson $19,900.00
David Johnson $32,500.00
Joan Johnson $5,990.00
Sam Hartmann $10,000.00
Mae Hartmann $125,100.00
North Hartmann $2,000.00
Michelle Hartmann $25,000.00
John Johnson $12,500.00
Martin Hartmann $19,900.00
David Hartmann $32,500.00
Joan Hartmann $5,990.00
```

and my code is here

```
private void btnReadInSalesData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("SalesNumbers.txt");
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    int intTotal = 0;

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { '$' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string s in tokens)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(s, out intTotal))
                numbers.Add(intTotal);
            lstTotalSales.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

And here is a picture of the output
http://s24.postimg.org/ylm8vl9at/output.jpg

Simply I want to read the text file and add the total sales to lstTotalSales listbox and add The Full name to lstNames list box.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to split each line into name and value.

Try this:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("SalesNumbers.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines) {
            string[] s = line.Split("$".ToCharArray());
            if (s.Length<2) { /* */ }
            double d;
            if (!double.TryParse(s[1], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out d)) {                
                // Handle if not a number
            }
            lstNames.Items.Add(s[0]);
            lstTotalSales.Items.Add(d);
        }
```

**EDIT**

While we convert the value to a double, you have to add the currency symbol when displaying the value:

```
string text = "$" + value.ToString();
```

Please note that we imply always splitting with the `$` symbol.

Assuming multiple currency symbols, you have to keep track of the split symbol:

```
string currencySymbols = "$€Y";
//...
int index = line.IndexOfAny(currencySymbols.ToCharArray());
if (index<0) {} //Nothing found
char usedSymbol = line[index];            // <- found symbol
string name = line.Substring(0, index);
string value = line.Substring(index+1);
//...
```

Comment: Error 2 The name 'NumberStyles' does not exist in the current context
 
Error 3 The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Also your loop is open !

Comment: To fix both errors you have to insert `using System.Globalization;`. Also you should never just copy some code, assuimg it's THE solution. ALWAYS have a look at it and try to understand what it does. All people here try to help and make some kick-start code, making a suggestion how to solve things. What do you mean by open loop?

Comment: Thank you joe, You are right I should loot at the solution before ask sorry for being lazy.
Same question here: Is there any way to keep the currency symbol in the TotalSales ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `decimal` instead of `int`, because your numbers are not integers.

You should also change your logic within the loop. I think it should be more like that:

```
foreach (string s in tokens)
{
    if (decimal.TryParse(s, out decTotal))
    {
        numbers.Add(decTotal);
        lstTotalSales.Items.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        lstNames.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Marcin, Is there any way to keep the currency symbol in the TotalSales ?